# Change carousel columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, react-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with 3 columns, but I want it to 2 columns for a medium screen and 1 column for a small screen. How can I achieve it?

When I adjust it to a medium screen I want the item3 to shift to next carousel item.
carousel slider images:
[carousel item1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeirJ.png)
[carousel item2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZO9.png)
This is a react bootstrap code.

```js
<Carousel datainterval="false">
            <Carousel.Item>
                <Row style={{ width: "80%", margin: "auto" }}>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img3.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item1</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img1.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item2</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img2.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item3</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
                <Row style={{ width: "80%", margin: "auto" }}>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img4.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item4</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img5.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item5</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                              <img src="../images/img6.jpeg" width="100%" />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={6}>
                                <h3>item6</h3>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. A picture showing what you mean would be helpful as well

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the md for medium screen, change its query and set md={6} and sm={12}. So you set up for a medium screen 2 columns and for a screen a column

[Example](https://www.codeply.com/go/ojz5BDpOej/bootstrap-4-carousel-with-grid-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can try bootstrap display property for columns you want to hide.
Example:

```
<div class="d-lg-none">hide on screens wider than lg</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Not hide, I want to shift it to next carousel item.